# How to run function in python after exiting command line

Tags: python, macos, terminal, google-drive-api

I want to run a function after I "command c" on terminal. I am scraping some data onto a file using python, and then I want to immediately close and push the file to google drive when I terminate the scraping process.I have written two different files for scraping and pushing but I would like to do this all in one file. How do I indicate the change of "command c" in python? If command c..do this...

Any help would be super useful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The sequence <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (or <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on Mac) causes a [`KeyboardInterrupt`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/exceptions.html#KeyboardInterrupt) exception to be raised.
You can simply catch this exception, with a simple `try`-`except`.

For instance, the following code will run a dummy work that takes some time, and on a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, will stop that work and print its current state.

```
import time

try:
    for i in range(100):
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print(i)
```

Note that, as specified [in the doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/exceptions.html#KeyboardInterrupt), the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception inherits from `BaseException` but **not** from `Exception`.
As a consequence, a `except Exception` clause would not catch a `KeyboardInterrupt`, while a `except BaseException` would catch both `KeyboardInterrupt` and `Exception`.

Comment: Hello, this is very useful-thanks! How do I let it run for no set time? I don't want to use for i in range....I want it to keep on running forever until keyboard interrupt

Comment: @torylor Of course, that's just a placeholder. All you need to do is put the body of your program in a `try` block, and put a `except KeyboardInterrupt` clause right after that block. I recently did the same, with a load of tests running, and the outcome being committed to a Git at the end - I wanted to save a partial outcome when I manually interrupted the tests.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `atexit` module https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html
create a handler function to do the persisting part. register it with `atexit` to run at the exit.

```
def goodbye(name, adjective):
    print 'Goodbye, %s, it was %s to meet you.' % (name, adjective)

import atexit
atexit.register(goodbye, 'Donny', 'nice')
```